# List evaluation in LISP (strange behaviour of cons)

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, racket, cons

I am currently playing around with LISP. Everything is fine, but I can't understand the following issue.

I have the this append-operation:

```
(define (append l1 l2)
   (if (eq? l1 null)
      l2
      (cons (first l1)
            (myappend (rest l1) l2))))
```

I use it like this:

```
(myappend (cons (cons 1 2) null) '(4 5))
```

And the result in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/)  is:

```
 '((1 . 2) 4 5)
```

But why? In my oppinion it should be **'(1 2 4 5)**, because cons returns a list and myappends appends two lists. Can anybody help me? What is LISP doing?

Comment: You seem to be using some nonstandard features peculiar to Racket. In Lisp (ANSI Common Lisp) lists are terminated by the symbol `nil`. In standard Scheme (of which Racket is evidently a dialect), lists are not terminated by a symbol. They are terminated by an empty list object which is written `()` (and which must be quoted when used as an expression: `'()`). In Scheme you use `(null? x)` to test whether `x` is the empty list, not `(eq x null)`; there is no predefined `null`.  In Common Lisp, it's `(null x)` or `(not x)` or `(eq x nil)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cons` returns a dotted pair, not necessarily a list.

`(cons 1 2)` returns `(1 . 2)`

`(cons 1 null)` returns `(1)`

`(cons 1 (cons 2 null))` returns `(1 2)`

Comment: Ok, thank you. But way (cons 1 (cons 2 null)) doesn't return (1 .(2))?

Comment: @Thomas: Both expressions represent the same structure; the convention is to prefer list notation instead of dotted pair notation whenever possible.  If some cons cell in the structure has a cdr that's a non-null atom (as in your question), dotted pair notation will be required because the structure is not a list.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379759/1281433) (disclaimer: it's mine) has more about the printed representation of cons cells.

Answer (score 4):

A `(cons 1 2)` will return an object whose first pointer (`car`) points to 1, and the other (`cdr`) points to 2, that's why it get printed in the dot-pair fashion.

Also you may want to understand deeper, I will recommend you read the [CL: gentle introduction to symbolic computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/), "6.4. Comparing CONS, LIST, AND APPEND", which explained these topics really well.

Answer (score 2):

Try what (cons 1 2) returns. Is it a list?

Comment: Obviously not. I think I missed something. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

to @ThomasUhrig : the following info might help you.

Although we are talking about Lisp language here, I notice that a line from **Page 8 and 9** of a famous Book named ["The Little Schemer (4th edition)"](http://books.google.com/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&lpg=PA9&dq=little+schemer+%22law+of+cons%22&pg=PA9&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=little%20schemer%20%22law%20of%20cons%22&f=false) help me understand the 2 puzzling facts altogether:

```
    Why (cons 1    2) does not look like '(1 2)?
    Why (cons 1 '(2)) does     look like '(1 2)?
    ----
    > (cons 1 2)
    (1 . 2)
    > (cons 1 '(2))
    (1 2)
    > '(1 2)
    (1 2)
```

> Just read the **"The Laws of Cons"**:
>
> The **primitive** *`cons`* takes 2 arguments.
>
> The 2nd argument to *`cons`* must be a list.
>
> The result is a list.
>
> **In practice:** (**cons** A B) works for ***all values A and B***, And
>
> > (**car** (**cons** A B)) = A
> >
> > (**cdr** (**cons** A B)) = B

Comment: The link to the PDF doesn't work anymore.  I can still find copies easily with Google, but it appears to still be on sale in places;  I'm not sure whether it's supposed to be freely distributed.  That said, the relevant "Law of Cons" is available in the Google Books [preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&lpg=PA9&dq=little%20schemer%20%22law%20of%20cons%22&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q=little%20schemer%20%22law%20of%20cons%22&f=false).