# Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?

Tags: lisp, scheme

```
(define ..
  (lambda (start stop)
    (cond ((> (add1 start) stop) (quote ()))
          ((eq? (add1 start) stop) (sub1 stop))
          (else (cons start (.. (add1 start) stop))))))
```

I have defined a simple range function.
The intent is for

```
(.. 1 5)  -->  (1 2 3 4)
```

Instead, a bizarre period is being added to my tuple and I have no idea why:

```
(.. 1 5)  -->  (1 2 3 . 4)
```

I don't understand why this is happening.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which case in the `cond` is used when you do `(.. 1 2)`? What does it return?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A list in Scheme is either the empty list `()` (also known as `nil` in some Lisps), or a cons cell whose `car` (also known as `first`) is an element of the list and whose `cdr` (also known as `rest`) is either the rest of the list (i.e., another list), or an atom that terminates the list.  The conventional terminator is the empty list `()`;  lists terminated by `()` are said to be "proper lists".  Lists terminated by any other atom are called "improper lists".  The list `(1 2 3 4 5)` contains the elements 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, and is terminated by `()`.  You could construct it by

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 ())))))
```

Now, when the system *prints* a cons cell, the general case is to print it by

```
(car . cdr)
```

For instance, the result of `(cons 1 2)` is printed as

```
(1 . 2)
```

Since lists are built of cons cells, you can use this notation for lists too:

```
'(1 2 3 4 5) ==
'(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . ())))))
```

That's rather clunky, though, so most lisps (all that I know of) have a special case for printing cons cells:  if the `cdr` is a list (either another cons cell, or `()`), then don't print the `.`, and don't print the surrounding parenthesis of the `cdr` (which it would otherwise have, since it's a list).  So, if you're seeing a result like

```
(1 2 3 . 4)
```

it means you've got an improper list that is terminated by the atom `4`.  It has the structure

```
(1 . (2 . (3 . 4)))
```

Now the question is: where in your code did the list construction go awry? `..` is always supposed to return a proper list, so let's look at the cases:  The first case always returns a proper list (the empty list):

```
((> (add1 start) stop) (quote ()))
```

The second case looks like it can return something that's not a list (assuming that `(sub1 stop) == (- stop 1)`):

```
((eq? (add1 start) stop) (sub1 stop))
```

Now, if `..` were functioning correctly, then the third case would always be returning a proper list (since `(cons x y)` is a proper list if `y` is):

```
(else (cons start (.. (add1 start) stop)))
```

Make your second case return a list and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you for your advice - the explanation was clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression `(sub1 stop)` needs to read `(list (sub1 stop))`

In order for `cons` to build up a proper list, the second element needs to be a list itself.  Thus, your function `..` should return a list of some type for every `cond` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part of the cond

```
 ((eq? (add1 start) stop) (sub1 stop))
```

It's causing a premature finish.