# Why does this LISP code emit periods or complain that lists must not end in 4?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I just started learning LISP today just for the heck of it, so I am completely new to it. I do have experience in other languages though. I tried to write a function that returns a list exactly as is, except without the last element.

While I intend to rewrite this function anyway since I'm sure there's a simpler way of doing it, my version produced some very unusual output. For the record, I'm using the CLISP environment.

```
(defun my-butlast (L)
    (if (null (rest L))
      nil
      (if (eq nil (my-butlast (rest L)))
         (first L)
         (cons (first L) (my-butlast (rest L)))
      )
    )
)

(my-butlast '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

This produced the output `(1 2 3 . 4)`

And so my question is, where did the point come from?

Also, if I try to run `(length (my-butlast '(1 2 3 4)))` I get a mystifying error: A proper list must not end with 4. What does that mean?

Comment: You don't need the second if. Change the alternative to the second if alternative since (list x) is the same as (cons x '())

Comment: Please spend a few minutes learning [how to format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is used in the representation of a `cons` whose `cdr` is not `NIL`. E.g.

```
(cons 1 2)
```

is displayed as

```
(1 . 2)
```

Consider what happens in your function if you do

```
(my-butlast '(1 2))
```

The test `(eq nil (my-butlast (rest L))` will be true, so it returns `(first L)`. Notice that this is just the number `1`, *not* a list containing `1`. You need to change to:

```
(if (eq nil (my-butlast (rest L)))
    (list (first L))
    (cons (first L) (my-butlast (rest L)))
)
```

Incidentally, it's more idiomatic to write `(null (my-butlast (rest L)))`.

Comment: There's a bit more detail about printed representation of lists and proper versus improper lists in [my answer to a distinct, but related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379759/1281433).

Answer (score 2):

Try doing I believe for your base case (it's been a while since I wrote lisp):

```
(list (first L))
```

(first L) will not return a list and cons of one element to another will create the structure you are looking at. Essentially your linked list is ending in [3|4] instead of [3|->] [4|0] with my lame ascii box diagrams.