# Is ((1 2) 3) the same as ((1 2) . 3)?

Tags: scheme, racket

I've been given an assignment in Scheme (using DrRacket) that asks me to create the list ((1 2) 3) using cons, from the components 1, 2, 3 and ()

I've managed to get as far as ((1 2) . 3) using:

```
(cons (cons '1 (cons '2 '())) '3)
```

However, is that the same thing?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379759/1281433) (disclaimer, it's my answer) to question where someone was getting output like `((1 2) . 3)` instead of `((1 2) 3)` explains the printed notation of lists and cons cells.  The short answer is that `((1 2) 3)` and `((1 2) . 3)` are _not_ the same. The first is `(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 ())) (cons 3 ()))` and the second is `(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 ())) 3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: this is cannibalized from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379759/1281433) to [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433)  The question is different (so not a duplicate), but the background explanation of how lists are constructed from cons cells, and how they're printed is the same.  The end is a bit different.*

A list in Scheme is either the empty list `()` (also known as `nil` in some Lisps), or a cons cell whose `car` (also known as `first`) is an element of the list and whose `cdr` (also known as `rest`) is either the rest of the list (i.e., another list), or an atom that terminates the list.  The conventional terminator is the empty list `()`;  lists terminated by `()` are said to be "proper lists".  Lists terminated by any other atom are called "improper lists".  The list `(1 2 3 4 5)` contains the elements 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, and is terminated by `()`.  You could construct it by

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 ())))))
```

Now, when the system *prints* a cons cell, the general case is to print it by

```
(car . cdr)
```

For instance, the result of `(cons 1 2)` is printed as

```
(1 . 2)
```

Since lists are built of cons cells, you can use this notation for lists too:

```
'(1 2 3 4 5)                      ; ==
'(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . (5 . ())))))
```

That's rather clunky, though, so most lisps (all that I know of) have a special case for printing cons cells:  if the `cdr` is a list (either another cons cell, or `()`), then don't print the `.`, and don't print the surrounding parenthesis of the `cdr` (which it would otherwise have, since it's a list).

With this understanding of lists and cons cells, we can consider the specific cases `((1 2) 3)` and `((1 2) . 3)`.  Let's break each of these down into the cons cells.

```
((1 2) 3)                              ; ==
((1 . (2 . ()) . (3 . ()))             ; ==
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 ()) (cons 3 ()))
```

```
((1 2) . 3)                   ; ==           
((1 . (2 . ())) . 3)          ; ==
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 ())) 3)
```

The last lines in each case are different, so `((1 2) 3)` and `((1 2) . 3)` are *not* the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, as others have mentioned, `((1 2) 3)` is the same as `((1 2) 3 . ())`, which of course you can build using  `(cons '3 '())` instead of the literal `'3`:

```
(cons (cons '1 (cons '2 '())) (cons '3 '()))
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

The "top-level" element of `(A . B)` is a single `cons` cell: `(cons A B)`. The `car` of the cons cell is `A` and the `cdr` is `B`. In a proper list, the `cdr` elements are always either `()` or other nonempty proper lists.

In contrast, `(A B)` is a two-element list, with one cons cell for each element: `(cons A (cons B ()))`

Answer (score 1):

They are different. `((1 2) 3)` is a `'()` terminated list while `((1 2) . 3)` is just a "pair". Try replacing    `'3` with `(cons '3 '())`

Answer (score 1):

They're different:

```
(equal? '((1 2) 3) '((1 2) . 3))
=> #f
```

Because `'((1 2) 3)` is equivalent to this:

```
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 '())) (cons 3 '()))
```

Whereas `'((1 2) . 3)` is equivalent to this:

```
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 '())) 3)
```

So you see, they have a different `cons` cell structure. The first version is a *proper list* - meaning: it ends in the empty list `'()`, whereas the second version ends in `3`, making it an *improper list*.