# How do I get rid of the #<void> that results from this recursive Scheme function?

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm supposed to write a recursive function that applies another function to a set of consecutive integers and returns a list. If start is > than stop, I'm just supposed to return an empty set.

Here's what I've got. I'm not sure this is the best solution to the problem, but...

```
(define (myfunction start stop fn)
  (if (<= start stop)
      (cons (fn start)(myfunction (+ start 1) stop fn)))
 )

(define (foo val1) ; just to demonstrate myfunction
  (* val1 2))
```

When I try to use it in the scheme interpreter, I get this:

```
(myfunction 0 5 foo)
(0 2 4 6 8 10 . #<void>)
```

What can I do to get rid of the void thing? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what happens if you do:

```
> (list (if #f 'then-value))
;=> (#<void>)
```

Your function has an `if` without an "else" part.

```
(define (myfunction start stop fn)
  (if (<= start stop)
      (cons (fn start)
            (myfunction (+ start 1) stop fn))
      ; missing something here
 ))
```

What should the list be when it's *not* the case that `(<= start stop)`?  I'd guess that a reasonable default would be the empty list, so that when `(myfunction (+ start 1) stop fn)` is finally called with values of `start` and `stop` such that `start` is greater than `stop`, you get the empty list, so that `(cons (fn start) (myfunction ...))` has an empty list as its second argument:

```
(define (myfunction start stop fn)
  (if (<= start stop)
      (cons (fn start)
            (myfunction (+ start 1) stop fn))
      '()))

(myfunction 0 5 (lambda (x) (* x 2)))
;=> (0 2 4 6 8 10)
```

For more about why the output was `(<elements> . #<void>)` (i.e., why it's got the dot at the end), have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379759/1281433) (disclaimer: it's my answer) to [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433).