# list not accepting special character at end

Tags: lisp

I am trying examples from this [page](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/310/pwfong/Lisp/3/tutorial3.html) While I am trying to create a post-order traversal seeing example of pre-order traversal,

```
(defun bin-tree-postorder (B)
  "Create a list containing keys of B in preorder."
  (if (bin-tree-leaf-p B)
      (list (bin-tree-leaf-element B))
    (let ((elmt  (bin-tree-node-element B))
          (left  (bin-tree-node-left    B))
          (right (bin-tree-node-right   B)))
      (cons (bin-tree-postorder left)
            (cons (bin-tree-postorder right) elmt)))))
```

I am getting `(((2) (3) . +) ((7) (8) . -) . *)`
But I desire '(2 3 + 7 8 - *). When I try to use `append` it says " **APPEND: A proper list must not end with**" error. In case of prepend its fine to append any 
+, -, / etc but at the end why is it complaining ?

I need help on fixing this.

Comment: Please make sure that your code is properly indented and formatted.

Comment: @RainerJoswig : I don't have much experience with lisp, I would take note of this for future posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not constructing what you what to in this code:

```
(cons (bin-tree-postorder left)
      (cons (bin-tree-postorder right)
            elmt))
```

Consider the following:

```
> (cons 2 (cons 3 '+))
(2 3 . +)

> (cons (list 2) (cons (list 3) '+))
((2) (3) . +)
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218730/1281433) to [Dot notation in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433) for more about what the `.` notation in a list means, but the condensed version is that a proper list in Lisps (including Scheme) is either:

- the empty list `()`; or
- a cons cell whose `car` is the first element of the list and whose `cdr` is a *proper* list that is the rest of the list.

That means that to make a list `(2 3 +)`, you would need the equivalent of

```
(cons 2 (cons 3 (cons '+ '())))
```

What you've actually got is different:

You're not constructing what you what to in this code:

```
(cons (bin-tree-postorder left)
      (cons (bin-tree-postorder right)
            elmt))
```

- Since `left` is `2`, `(bin-tree-postorder left)` is `(2)`
- Since `right` is `3`, `(bin-tree-postorder right)` is `(3)`
- Since `elmt` is `+`, `elmt` is `(3)`

Then what you've got is

```
> (cons '(2) (cons '(3) '+))
((2) (3) . '+)
```

If you want to use `append`, then you'll need to make the last argument a proper list.  E.g.:

```
(append (bin-tree-postorder left) (bin-tree-postorder right) (list elmt))
```