# In Scheme, how can I understand "(define (f x . y) (cons x y))"

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I'm new to Scheme, here I get in trouble with dotted list, here is an example:

`(define (f x . y) (cons x y))`

When I enter:  `(f 1 2 3)` the result is `'(1 2 3)`. Yes, it returns a list, and at this time

`x => 1` and `y => '(2 3)`.

My question is how could the interpreter know this when `f` takes unfixed length of args?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm new to Scheme, here I get in trouble with dotted list, here is an
>   example:
>
> ```
> (define (f x . y) (cons x y))
> ```
>
> When I enter:  (f 1 2 3) the result is '(1 2 3). Yes, it returns a
>   list, and at this time
>
> ```
> x => 1 and y => '(2 3).
> ```
>
> My question is how could the interpreter know this when f takes
>   unfixed length of args?

It's not quite right to say that `f` takes an unfixed, or arbitrary, number of arguments.  It doesn't.  It requires *at least* one argument.  If you try calling `(f)`, you'll get an error.  The key to understanding what's going on here may be understanding the dotted pair notation in Lisps.  It's covered in another Stack Overflow question, [Dot notation in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433), but the short version is that every list is built from pairs.  A single pair can be written as `(car . cdr)`.  E.g., `(cons 1 2) => (1 . 2)`.   A list like `(1 2 3)` is actually a pair whose `cdr` is another pair whose `cdr` is another pair, etc.:  `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`.  Because that's awkward to read, we typically remove all but the last dot when we write a chain of pairs, and if the last `cdr` is `()`, we omit the dot and `()`, too.  So

```
(1 . (2 . (3 . 4))  === (1 2 3 . 4)
(1 . (2 . (3 . ())) === (1 2 3)
```

Noete that while the default printer won't print it this way, the list `(1 2 3 4)` can also be written in these ways:

```
(1 . (2 3 4)) === (1 2 . (3 4)) === (1 2 3 . (4))
```

While it won't print that way, you can write that and the system will understand it.  E.g.,

```
> '(1 2 . (3 4))
(1 2 3 4)
```

That may be the key to understanding the lambda-list notation.  When we write a lambda list for a function, it represents a function, and that lambda list gets destructured against the arguments.  So, if we have following lambda lists and use them to destructure the argument list `(1 2 3)`, we get the resulting bindings:

```
lambda-list    x             y      z
-------------------------------------
(x y z)        1             2      3
(x y . z)      1             2    (3)
(x . y)        1         (2 3)    n/a
x              (1 2 3)     n/a    n/a
```

That last case might be surprising, but you can test that all of these actually work as expected:

```
((lambda (x y z)   (list x y z)) '(1 2 3)) => (1 2 3)
((lambda (x y . z) (list x y z)) '(1 2 3)) => (1 2 (3))
((lambda (x . y)   (list x y))   '(1 2 3)) => (1 (2 3))
((lambda x         (list x))     '(1 2 3)) => ((1 2 3))
```

That last one is kind of neat, because it means that if it weren't part of the language already, you could do:

```
(define (list . elements) elements)
```

Comment: Thanks, Joshua, you got me.

Answer (score 2):

In scheme, a `dot` before a formal parameter indicates that the parameters' value inside
the procedure will be a list, with all the remaining parameters. So as you correctly show in your post, `y` inside the procedure is a list, `'(2 3)`. In `f` x is treated as a normal parameter.

```
(define (f x . y)
 (display "y: ")
 (display y) (newline)) 

(f 1 2 'this 'is 'a 'list)
y: (2 this is a list)
```

Here is what Guile reference manual has to say about this:

> (variable1 … variablen . variablen+1)
>
> If a space-delimited period precedes the last variable, then the procedure takes n or > more variables where n is the number of formal arguments before the period. There must be at least one argument before the period. The first n actual arguments will be stored into the newly allocated locations for the first n formal arguments and the sequence of the
> remaining actual arguments is converted into a list and the stored into the location for  the last formal argument. If there are exactly n actual arguments, the empty list is
> stored into the location of the last formal argument.

Comment: It's more proper to call it a "dot" rather than a "period". Cons cells are sometimes called "dotted pairs".

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter knows that `f` has an argument named `x` followed by the argument list `y`. So when it encounters the call to `f`, it puts the first argument into `x` and the remaining ones into `y`.

Comment: Does the interpreter also know that the args `1 2 3` would be parsed into a list `'(1 2 3)`?

Comment: @kedebug The interpreter knows that `(cons 1 '(2 3))` evaluates to `'(1 2 3)` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that `f` takes `1 2 3`, it could be three args, but it parsed into a list `'(1 2 3)`. Hard for me to understand this.

Comment: @kedebug it is not parsed into `'(1 2 3)`. You create that list in the body of your procedure with `(cons 1 '(2 3))`

Answer (score 0):

The `(f x . y)` syntax means that the first argument to `define` is an "improper" list (is is equivalent to what you would get from `(cons 'f (cons 'x 'y))` rather than from `(cons 'f (cons 'x (cons 'y nil)))`. So when the function is called, each thing is bound in turn. First, x is bound to 1, then the rest of the list is bound to the tail of the arument list. Since that, at this point, is a symbol, y is bound to '(2 3).

Comment: You can use dot notation to express a proper list ('a . '()) is a proper list. A cons cell is comprised of two pointers. So when used in an argument list like so it's a way of binding the contents of the `cdr` pointer to a value, rather than each of the `car`'s contents in turn.