# Creating a pair of pairs using Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, cons

I need to create a pair that contains two pairs inside using Common Lisp.

The output needs to be:
`((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))`

Literature states `(cons (cons 1 2) (cons 3 4))` should output what I need but when I run that I obtain:
`((1 . 2) 3 . 4)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216711/dot-notation-in-scheme)  That question is asking about the case in Scheme, but Common Lisp and Scheme's conses and printing conventions are the same.  It might not be a duplicate (note 'possible'), but I the answer there that explains the printing conventions of cons cells and dots will explain why `((1 . 2) 3 . 4)` and `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))` are just different visual representations of the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

In Lisp

((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))

and

((1 . 2) 3 . 4)

are exactly the same thing. You can check by evaluating `'((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))`.

If you think about it the `3` is the car of the cdr, so it's the second element of the improper list, so the pair `(1 . 2)` is the first element, `3` as second element and that has `4` instead of NIL to terminate it.

They're just two ways to see the very same cons cells configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
CL-USER 4 > (equal '((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))
                   '((1 . 2)    3 . 4 ))
T
```

Answer (score 1):

`#xA` is the exact same as `10`, but when it's printed it's system settings that dictates how a number is to be printed. The reason is that the fixnum doesn't have a base, but the visual representation does. Just as `#xA` is the same as `10`, `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))` is the same as `((1 . 2) 3 . 4)`.

The illusion is that we have lists. In order to do that we display pairs with either nil or a pair as tails differently than pairs that has other values as their tail.. A list `(1 2)` is modeled as `(1 . (2 . ()))`. The rules are something like this: Whenever the tail is nil or a pair you can omit this pair dot and the first parenthesis of the tail. Apply it recursively and `(1 . (2 . ()))` displays as `(1 2)` and `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))` displays as `((1 . 2) 3 . 4).

To make the illusion complete the reader does the reverse so when it reads `(1 2)` it creates `(1 . (2 . ()))` in memory.

To really be a good Lisp programmer (in any dialect) you need to be able to see the omitted dot and parentheses in `(1 2)`. When you do it becomes obvious what you need to do with  `(a (b c) d)` in order to retrieve `c` (It's obviously `(cadadr '(a (b c) d))`). When you do master this you'll "see" `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))`.

Answer (score -2):

This will do it: `(cons (cons 1 2) (cons (cons 3 4) empty))`

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that is closer to what I need, however it still doesn't provide the point separating the two pairs

Comment: is `empty` supposed to be `'()` or `nil`?

Comment: This is `((1 . 2) (3 . 4))` which is not the structure that @Higgins is asking for.