# Difference between ("v" 1) and ("v" . 1)

Tags: scheme

Starting to learn scheme and I come across this:

What is the difference between

```
("v" . 1)
```

and

```
("v" 1)
```

They seem to work the same, just want to know what the difference. I tend to use `("v" 1)`, but `( cons "v" 1 )` returns `("v" . 1)`. So, what's the difference?

Thank you

Comment: You may find [dot notation in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433) useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`("v" 1)` is equal to `(cons "v" (cons 1 '()))` or `("v" . (1 . '()))`.

`(foo . bar)` is how a cons-cell is printed when it is not a proper list. A proper list is the constant `'()` (representing the empty list) or a cons-cell whose second element is a proper list. A proper list gets printed as `(x1 x2 x3 etc)` where the `xi` are the first elements of each cons-cell.