# How does "Cons" work in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cons

I was studying Lisp and I am not experienced in Lisp programming. In a part of my studies I encountered the below examples:

```
> (cons ‘a ‘(a b))  ----> (A A B)
> (cons ‘(a b) ‘a)  ----> ((A B).A)
```

I was wondering why when we have **(cons ‘a ‘(a b))** the response is **(A A B)** and why when we change it a little and put the **'a** after **(a b)**, the response is a dotted list like **((A B).A)**? What is the difference between the first code line and the second one? What is going on behind these codes?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216711/dot-notation-in-scheme

Comment: I found this book very helpful for learning: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's pretty easy to understand if you think of them as [cons-cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons).

In short, a cons cell consists of *exactly* two values. The normal notation for this is to use the dot, e.g.:

```
(cons 'a 'b) ==> (A . B)
```

But since lists are used so often in LISP, a better notation is to drop the dot.
Lists are made by having the second element be a new cons cell, with the last ending a terminator (usually nil, or `'()` in Common Lisp). So these two are equal:

```
(cons 'a (cons 'b '())) ==> (A B)
(list 'a 'b) ==> (A B)
```

So `(cons 'a 'b)` creates a cell `[a,b]`, and `(list 'a 'b)` will create `[a, [b, nil]]`.  Notice the convention for encoding lists in cons cells: They terminate with an inner `nil`.

Now, if you cons `'a` onto the last list, you create a new cons cell containing `[[a, [b, nil]], a]`. As this is not a "proper" list, i.e. it's not terminated with a `nil`, the way to write it out is to use the dot: `(cons '(a b) 'a) ==> ((a b) . a)`.

If the dot wasn't printed, it would have to have been a list with the structure `[[a, [b, nil]], [a, nil]]`.

**Your example**

When you do `(cons 'a '(a b))` it will take the symbol `'a` and the list `'(a b)` and put them in a new cons cell.  So this will consist of `[a, [a, [b, nil]]]`.  Since this naturally ends with an inner `nil`, it's written without dots.

As for `(cons '(a b) 'a)`, now you'll get `[[a, [b, nil]], a]`. This does *not* terminate with an inner `nil`, and therefore the dot notation will be used.

Can we use cons to make the last example end with an inner nil? Yes, if we do

```
(cons '(a b) (cons 'a '())) ==> ((A B) A)
```

And, finally,

```
(list '(a b) 'a))
```

is equivalent to

```
(cons (cons (cons 'a (cons 'b '())) (cons 'a '())))
```

Comment: Thanks but what is the difference between (cons ‘a ‘(a b)) and (cons ‘(a b) ‘a) and why these two act differently?

Comment: @AmirJalilifard They don't act differently.  (cons 'a '(a b)) returns a cons cell whose car is 'a and whose cdr is '(a b).  On the other hand (cons '(a b) 'a) returns a cons cell whose car is '(a b) and whose cdr is 'a.  Cons cells are just pair.  Instead of cons, car, and cdr, you could say make-pair, left, and right and get the same behavior.  makePair(2,3) is obviously different from makePair(3,2) because in the first one, 2 and 3 are left and right, and in the second, 2 and 3 are right and left.

Answer (score 8):

See this visualization:

```
CL-USER 7 > (sdraw:sdraw '(A A B))

[*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |        |
 v        v        v
 A        A        B

CL-USER 8 > (sdraw:sdraw '((A B) . A))

[*|*]--->A
 |
 v
[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |
 v        v
 A        B
```

Also:

```
CL-USER 9 > (sdraw:sdraw '(A B))

[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |
 v        v
 A        B

CL-USER 10 > (sdraw:sdraw (cons 'A '(A B)))

[*|*]--->[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |        |
 v        v        v
 A        A        B

CL-USER 11 > (sdraw:sdraw (cons '(A B) 'A))

[*|*]--->A
 |
 v
[*|*]--->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |
 v        v
 A        B
```

Answer (score 5):

A `cons` is a data structure that can contain two values. Eg `(cons 1 2) ; ==> (1 . 2)`. The first part is `car`, the second is `cdr`. A `cons` is a `list` if it's `cdr` is either `nil` or a `list`. Thus
 `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` is a list.

When printing `cons` the dot is omitted when the `cdr` is a `cons` or `nil`. The outer parentheses of the `cdr` is also omitted.  Thus `(3 . ())` is printed `(3)` and `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` is printed `(1 2 3)`.  It's the same structure, but with different visualization. A `cons` in the `car` does not have this rule.

The read function reads `cons` with dot and the strange exceptional print format when the `cdr` is a list. It will at read time behave as if it were `cons`.

With a special rule for both `read` and `print` the illusion of a list is complete even when it's chains of `cons`.

```
(cons ‘a ‘(a b))  ----> (A . (A B)) 
(cons ‘(a b) ‘a)  ----> ((A B) . A)
```

When printing, the first is one list of 3 elements since the `cdr` is a list.

Answer (score 3):

A list (a b c) is represented (stored internally) as three cons-cells: `(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c '())`. Note that the last pair has '() in its cdr.

Series of cons-cells whose last cdr is '() is printed as a list by the printer. The example is thus printed as (a b c).

Let's look at:  `(cons 'a '(a b))`.

The list '(a b) is represented as (cons 'a (cons 'b '()). This means that
`(cons 'a '(a b))` produces: `(cons 'a (cons 'a (cons 'b '()))`.

Let's look at: `(cons '(a b) 'a)`.

The list '(a b) is represented as (cons 'a (cons 'b '()). This means that
`(cons (cons '(a b) 'a))` produces `(cons (cons 'a (cons 'b '()) 'a)`.

Note that this series does not end in `'()`. To show that the printer uses dot notation. `( ... . 'a)` means that a value consists of a series of cons-cells and that the last cdr contains `'a`. The value `(cons (cons 'a (cons 'b '()) 'a)` is thus printed as `'((a b) . a)`.

Answer (score -1):

cons is just a pair data type. For example, `(cons 1 2)` is a pair of `1` and `2`, and it will be printed with the two elements seperated by a dot like `(1 . 2)`.

Lists are internally represented as nested conses, e.g. the list `(1 2 3)` is `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))`.

Answer (score -2):

=> using sbcl in terminal

$ rlwrap sbcl

- (ql:quickload "draw-cons-tree")

  To load "draw-cons-tree":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
  draw-cons-tree
  ; Loading "draw-cons-tree"

("draw-cons-tree")

- (draw-cons-tree:draw-tree '(1 2 3 4))