# Function to search by values in different types of lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have 2 kinds of lists with key-value pairs:

```
(define pairs1 (list (list 1 2)(list 10 20)(list 100 200)))
(define pairs2 (list (cons 1 2)(cons 10 20)(cons 100 200)))
```

I want to search by value in both kinds of lists with one function.  I tried following ('cdr' in one and 'second' in other fn), but they work with one list each:

```
(define (assoc_val1 val spair)
  (for/list ((item spair) #:when (equal? (cdr item) val))
      item))

(define (assoc_val2 val spair)
  (for/list ((item spair) #:when (equal? (second item) val))
      item))
```

Can I have a function which works for both kinds of lists? Also, is there a good link explaining difference between (list 1 2), (cons 1 2) and '(1 2)?

---

Edit: Modifying the answer provided by @Sylwester , following function can detect and work on both lists:

```
(define (assoc2* haystack needle [is-equal? equal?] )
  (if (list? (car haystack))
      (findf (λ (e) (is-equal? needle (second e))) haystack)
      (findf (λ (e) (is-equal? needle (cdr e))) haystack)
      ))

(assoc2* pairs1 20)
(assoc2* pairs2 20)
```

Output:

```
'(10 20)
'(10 . 20)
```

Comment: For you last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984552/what-is-the-difference-between-quote-and-list

Comment: For the first: Why do you want to have two kinds of key-value representations. Pick one.

Comment: Thanks for the link which discusses mainly list and quote forms. Any link for list vs cons forms?  Also, what is the best way if  one  has to use key-value pairs heavily in an application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703516/how-does-cons-work-in-lisp/29704312#29704312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `#:accessor` as a keyword parameter or optional parameter:

```
;; Fully compatible with assoc but allows for searching any part 
(define (assoc* haystack needle [is-equal? equal?] #:accessor [accessor car])
  (findf (λ (e) (is-equal? needle (accessor e))) haystack))

(assoc* pairs1 20 #:accessor cadr) ; ==> (10 20)
(assoc* pairs2 20 #:accessor cdr)  ; ==> (10 . 20)
```

Comment: Can the code detect which type of list it is and apply relevant function?

Comment: @mso It depends.. Imagine you have a assoc with pair values, eg. `'((0 . (0 0)) (1 . (0 1)) (2 . (1 0))  (3 . (1 1)))`. As you know `(0 . (0 0))` is the same as `(0 0 0)` so how would it be possible to determine if the elements are pairs or list? You cannot, however if you know that the values are **never** pairs then you could do it, but it will no longer be a general procedure.

Comment: Pl see my modification of your code in the question above. Works since (cons  1 2) gives false with "list?" function.

Comment: @mso try with `(assoc2* '((0 . (0 0)) (1 . (0 1)) (2 . (1 0)) (3 . (1 1))) '(1 0))`. The correct answer is `(2 . (1 0))` but it returns `#f`. Thus my statement that in order to do this you can no longer have pairs as values and it's not longer a general procedure. `(assoc* '((0 . (0 0)) (1 . (0 1)) (2 . (1 0)) (3 . (1 1))) '(1 0) #:accessor cdr)` does the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.