# Scheme: how to produce '(5 . (5))

Tags: append, scheme, racket, cons

I have tried all kinds of combinations of cons and append to produce '(5 . (5)) but I couldn't. Is there any way?

Comment: Can you show your best try? So we can point you to the error and how to correct it.

Comment: I can't think of a way to get Racket to output exactly that – if the `cdr` of a pair is a proper list, it's not printed as a dotted pair. It would be better to ask how to create a specific structure than how to get a specific output format.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need the list represented like that? What procedure is consuming this result and why does it need it like that?

Comment: Look at this question: [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433).  The structure you want is just `(list 5 5)` or `(cons 5 (cons 5 '()))`, or `'(5 5)` or `'(5 . (5))`, etc.  But the standard printing will always be `(5 5)`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Its the matter with the printer not the internal structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the risk of sounding like Bill Clinton, it depends on what you mean by "produce".

If you mean "produce a value that prints on the screen as `'(5 . (5))`, then you're sort of out of luck, because this value prints as `'(5 5)`.

For a similar example: how do I produce the number `1e-1` ? Well, try typing it in; this is the same as 0.1, and if you type in 1e-1, it's going to print as 0.1.

However, you can evaluate

```
#lang racket
(= 0.1 1e-1)
```

... and you'll see that they're the same number.

In the same way, try evaluating

```
#lang racket
(equal? '(5 . (5)) (list 5 5))
```

and you'll see that these are two ways of writing the same value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to print proper list improperly. The easiest one would be write own printer. A very simple one would be something like the following:

```
(define (write-dot obj . maybe-port)
  (define out (if (null? maybe-port) (current-output-port) (car maybe-port)))
  (cond ((pair? obj) 
         (display "(" out)
         (write-dot (car obj) out)
         (let loop ((obj (cdr obj)))
           (display " " out)
           (cond ((null? obj))
                 ((and (pair? obj) (null? (cdr obj)))
                  (display ". " out)
                  (write obj out))
                 ((pair? obj) (write-dot (car obj)) (loop (cdr obj)))
                 (else (write obj)))
           (display ")" out)))
        (else (write obj out))))
```