# Pairs of pairs in Scheme

Tags: scheme

How do I create pairs of pairs in scheme. I mean representation like that:

```
(("x" . "y") . ("a" . "b"))

(cons (cons "x" "y") (cons "a" "b")) creates different thing (("x" . "y") "a" . "b")
```

Please help.

Comment: `(("x" . "y") "a" . "b")` and `(("x" . "y") . ("a" . "b"))` are equivalent, they are just different ways of printing it. You can always check the result with `car` and `cdr` if you want to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `(("x" . "y") . ("a" . "b"))` is equal to `(("x" . "y") "a" . "b")`, as you can see if you ask to the system:

```
(equal? '(("x" . "y") "a" . "b") '(("x" . "y") . ("a" . "b")))
```

They are printed differently since `(("x" . "y") "a" . "b")` is printed as an *improper list*. To see how you can obtain a printing like `(("x" . "y") . ("a" . "b"))` see for instance this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33996997/2382734).