# Lisp - Problems with postordering a binary tree

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, binary-tree, postorder

Learning lisp for the fun of it, haven't had too much of a difficult time until now, and I'm on the third lecture of [this site.](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/310/pwfong/Lisp/3/tutorial3.html) I'm trying to complete the exercise "Implement a function that will create a list containing members of a given binary tree in postorder." Here's my code so far:

```
(defun bin-tree-postorder (b)
  "Create a list containing keys of b in postorder"
  (if (bin-tree-leaf-p b)
      (list (bin-tree-leaf-element b))
    (let
        ((elmt (bin-tree-node-element b))
         (left (bin-tree-node-left b))
         (right (bin-tree-node-right b)))
  (cons
        (append (bin-tree-postorder left)
                    (bin-tree-postorder right)) elmt))))
```

However, it won't run, because I get an error of:

```
*** - APPEND: A proper list must not end with +
```

Here's my trace:

```
1. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(* (+ (2) (3)) (- (7) (8))))
2. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(+ (2) (3)))
3. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(2))
3. Trace: BIN-TREE-POSTORDER ==> (2)
3. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(3))
3. Trace: BIN-TREE-POSTORDER ==> (3)
2. Trace: BIN-TREE-POSTORDER ==> ((2 3) . +)
2. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(- (7) (8)))
3. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(7))
3. Trace: BIN-TREE-POSTORDER ==> (7)
3. Trace: (BIN-TREE-POSTORDER '(8))
3. Trace: BIN-TREE-POSTORDER ==> (8)
2. Trace: BIN-TREE-POSTORDER ==> ((7 8) . -)
```

I've tried using list instead of cons, which provides a partially correct answer in the form of a list-of-lists:

```
(((2 3) + (7 8) -) *)
```

However, the correct answer is:

```
(2 3 + 7 8 - *)
```

Could anyone who answers provide hints or pointers, instead of modified code, so I could better understand the problem? I'd rather not look at the tutorial's answers, because that won't help me learn what I'm doing wrong.

Rest assured I will turn it into a tail-recursive function after the basic recursive function is figured out.

Thank you for anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the values of **left**, **right**, and **elmt** when these calls to **cons** and **append** happen:

```
  (cons
        (append (bin-tree-postorder left)
                    (bin-tree-postorder right)) elmt))))
```

**bin-tree-postorder** *should* return a list, so the call to **append** *should* be OK.  (I know this isn't actually true yet, but we're working with the assumption that the recursive calls went OK.)  So now the function is going to return the value of:

```
(cons <appended-postorder-results> elmt)
```

Now, **elmt** is something like the symbols **+**.  Let's use the REPL to see what a call like this returns:

```
CL-USER> (cons '(2 3) '+)
((2 3) . +)
```

That's not what you wanted.  You wanted the list **(2 3 +)**.  To get that, you don't want to cons onto **elmt**, because then you'll get an improper list like the one shown above.  You may find *[Dot notation in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433)* useful for understanding what that `.` means.  Later calls to **append** will complain about the improper list, as you've seen:

```
CL-USER> (append '((2 3) . +) '(4 5))
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: LIST datum: +>.
```

The arguments to **append** have requirements that you might consider unusual if you haven't *implemented* **append** yourself.  The documentation for [**append**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm) says:

> #### Syntax:
>
> append &rest lists ⇒ result
>
> #### Arguments and Values:
>
> list—each must be a proper list except the last, which may be any
>   object.

The reason is that **append** has to walk to the end of each of the lists (except the list) to build a new list that is ultimately terminated by the (copy of) the next list.  That means "replacing" the final **nil** with the next list.  An improper list (like **(1 . 2)** doesn't have **nil** at end.

The easiest thing you can do is to simply remove the **cons**, and add an argument to **append**, namely a list containing **elmt**:

```
(append (bin-tree-postorder left)
        (bin-tree-postorder right)
        (list elmt))
```

Comment: Could live dangerously and `rplacd` or `rplaca`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`append` combines lists together; the `element` of a tree isn't a list.  So either you can't use `append`, or you have to make a list out of `element`.

Thus, the second case could be written as `(append (bin-tree-postorder left) (bin-tree-postorder right) (list elmt))`.

Comment: (list elmt) at the end of the cons form instead of elmt provides the partially correct answer. What else could I use instead of append?

Comment: @OrangeCalx01, note that the answer of @ScottHunter is correct, you should use `(append (bin-tree-postorder left) (bin-tree-postorder right) (list elmt))` and not `(cons (append (bin-tree-postorder left)(bin-tree-postorder right)) (list elmt))`. The first form will produce the correct answer `(2 3 + 7 8 - *)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `append`, you could use an accumulator to build up the list in reverse. Here is code that does that.

```
(defun bin-tree-postorder (b &optional accumulator)
  (if (bin-tree-leaf-p b)
      (cons (bin-tree-leaf-element b) accumulator)
      (bin-tree-postorder (bin-tree-node-left b)
                          (bin-tree-postorder (bin-tree-node-right b)
                                              (cons (bin-tree-node-element b)
                                                    accumulator)))))
```

What the function does is append the result of post ordering the tree to the accumulator. It works recursively by first adding the current element to the accumulator, appending the post ordering of the right subtree to the accumulator, and then appending the post ordering of the left subtree to the accumulator.

Answer (score -1):

`push` is what you're looking for -- push new elements onto the end of the list. `reverse` if necessary when done.

Comment: Someone want to explain why `push` isn't a feasible option?