# Why does the non-splicing comma after a dot splices the list inside a list template?

Tags: common-lisp

On page 68 from Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming by Peter Norvig we have the following code:

```
test               -> (a test)
`(this is ,test)   -> (this is (a test))
`(this is ,@test)  -> (this is a test)
```

So far so good. The splicing comma will explode the outer parentheses. However this code is not explained in the book:

```
`(this is . ,test) -> (this is a test)
```

**How does it work? What is happening under the hood?**

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216711/dot-notation-in-scheme) may be helpful background in general.  (It's about scheme, but the same principles apply to Common Lisp.)

Answer (score 3):

From the CLHS section on [backquote][1]:

> `` `(x1 x2 x3 ... xn . ,form) `` may be interpreted to mean
>
> ```
>     (append [ x1] [ x2] [ x3] ... [ xn] form)
> ```
>
> where the brackets indicate a transformation of an `xj` as described above.

So

```
`(this is . ,test)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(append '(this) '(is) test)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(append '(this is) test)
```

So it creates a list that begins with `this is` and the tail is the contents of `test`.

This parallels the syntax used to create dotted lists:

```
'(1 2 . 3)
```

because `3` is put in the `CDR` of the last `CONS` in the list, rather than putting `NIL` there as in proper lists. When you use backquote, it puts the whole list in that place, so it's like:

```
'(this is . (a test))
```

which is the same as

```
'(this is a test)
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is going on we have to revisit how lists are implemented in common lisp. Lists are a chain of cons cells ending with `nil` value.

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))) -> (1 2 3)
```

When we insert the dot at the end of a list we are signalling the reader that our final value is not going to be `nil` but a non-empty list. As non-empty lists are just a chain of cons cells we are basically saying: "continue the chain of cons cells with the beginning of this list. (in our example this non-empty list is `test` and has the value `(a test)`.

If our list doesn't end with `nil`, the reader will always show is this fact with a dot:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 3)              -> (1 2 . 3)
```

Comment: The terminator could still be an empty list.  You can do `(1 2 3 . ())`, after all.