# Association list in another association list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there any way to make something in lisp that can do like an association list in another association list, I tried  :

```
(setq alist '((A . B) (B . C) (C . (D . E))))
```

but it gives :

```
((A . B) (B . C) (C D . E))
```

and then do a something like:

```
(assoc 'd (assoc 'c alist))
```

and i get this error:

```
Maximum error depth exceeded (22 nested errors) with
'The value C is not of type LIST.'.
```

Comment: Seeing `'((A . B) (B . C) (C . (D . E)))` printed as `((A . B) (B . C) (C D . E))` isn't a bug.  See [dot notation in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216711/dot-notation-in-scheme).  (This is aside from the fact it doesn't produce an association list as a value in an association list.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`((A . B) (B . C) (C . (D . E)))` is not a nested assoc list.

```
((A . B)
 (B . C)
 (C . (D . E))  ; <-  (d . e)  is not an assoc list. Just one association.
)
```

You want to have a list of associations:  `((d . e))`.

Which makes it this solution:

```
CL-USER 5 > (assoc 'C '((A . B) (B . C) (C . ((D . E)))))
(C (D . E))

CL-USER 6 > (assoc 'd (cdr (assoc 'C '((A . B) (B . C) (C . ((D . E)))))))
(D . E)
```

Note that `'(C . (D . E))` and `(C D . E)` are both lists of the same structure,  just differently written:

```
CL-USER 8 > (equal '(C . (D . E)) '(C D . E))
T
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i found it,

```
(setq alist '((A . B) (B . C) (C . ((D . E)))))
(assoc  'd  ( cdr ( assoc 'c alist))) => (D . E)
```