# How to understand lists(cons structure) in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I'm just starting to learn common lisp. I do not understand well about lists' structure when I'm reading the Set and Tree chapter. Now I wonder what's exactly it like in the list. I know the cons include two values which can be any types of object. Here I found a picture by google.
But I'm very confused. It seems like general lists in data structure.
[lists in lisp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q12sF.png)

Comment: and what exactly is your question? i'm very confused. it seems like general blog entry.

Comment: sorry,my question may not clear, because my english is porr. Umm, Iwant to know how list is origanized in lisp?

Comment: can you please edit your question to include the question?

Comment: This question is probably too broad, but I think that the answer to [dot notation in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216711/dot-notation-in-scheme) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lists are build using cons cells you mentioned. single cons cell with nil in second part is the simplest list:

```
(cons 'A nil)
=> (A)
```

if you want to extend list, you cons another cell to it:

```
(cons 'C (cons 'B (cons 'A nil)))
=> (C B A)
```

so list is a series of linked together cons cells.

also, to make life easier there is `list` function. this way you don't have to write all those `cons` invocations and can create list like this:

```
(list 'C 'B 'A)
=> (C B A)
```

but inside it's still series of cons cells.