# Meaning of 'quote in Lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

This question arose when reading *SICP*. Why `(list 'quote '(a b c))` evaluated by the interpreter (*R5RS* in *Dr.Racket*) as `'(a b c)`. For me it should be `(quote (a b c))`. For instance `(list 'quot '(a b c))` is evaluated as `(quot (a b c))`. What is so special in the `'quote`?

Comment: What interpreter are you using?

Comment: Since the other answers are essentially duplicates, I'll add this here, to add to what they say: Even when you are looking at the single-quote syntax, what you are really seeing is a non-empty ***list***: `(consp ''42)` is true (returns non-`nil`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also took me a while to understand this problem. But it's just your good-hearted lisp interpreter showing (quote (a b c)) in it's equivalent form '(a b c). Since there is no such equivalence/syntactic sugar for (quott (a b c)), it's shown as is.

Comment: I think I begin to understand. If A = `(quote (a b c))`, and B = `'(a b c)`, and A is *equal* to B and they're  represented in the same way. So `(quote A)` must be equal to `(quote B)` and represented in the same way.

Comment: @Graduate `(quote A)` is not equal to `(quote B)` as `quote` isn't evaluating parameters. You end up with symbol `A` and symbol `B` which could get evaluated to the same thing later but quote doesn't evaluate.

Comment: You may also want to examine standard generic method print-object. If you `defmethod print-object` for your own classes, the Lisp-printer (the same printer that prints `(quote)` as `'` ), will print your object the way you want it, everywhere. I just tried overloading print-object for symbol `'quote` and interestingly, it didn't change anything for sbcl, but worked at LispWorks. I didn't know that this was undefined behaviour by the standard and even filed a bug for sbcl which luckily got rejected soon enough :/

Answer (score 6):

You'll get different behaviors depending on exactly what Lisp you're using (Scheme, Racket, Common Lisp, etc.) but in general, the system will accept `'x` as a *shorthand* or *syntactic sugar* for `(quote x)`. The two forms are exactly equivalent and their values are the same:  the unevaluated `x`. When a result is coming out of the system, it might choose to print in the first way to make the result more intuitive to the user.  A similar thing happens with `cons`, too.  For instance,

```
(cons 1 2)
;=> (1 . 2)
```

because that's the general way that cons cells (pairs) are printed.  However, there's a special case defined for when the second part of the pair is another list (either the empty list `()` or another pair, and that's why we have the following.  I've also written a bit more about how lists and cons cells are printed in an answer to [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433).

```
(cons 1 '())
;=> (1)

(cons 1 '(2 3))
;=> (1 2 3)
```

Now, I've written the *values* of the expression above.  E.g., the *value* of the form `(cons 1 '(2 3))` is the list `(1 2 3)`.  As an additional complication, some systems (I'm thinking of some languages is Dr. Racket, in particular) don't print the *value* of a form in the interactive prompt, but rather print a form that would produce the same (for certain interpretations of “the same”) values.  For instance, you might evaluate `'(1 . 2)` and see the output `(cons 1 2)` because that's another *form* that would produce the same value.  This can be helpful if you're doing *pure* functional programming that has [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29), but if you're not expecting it, it can lead to some confusion.

A good way to see that we're getting the results that we should, regardless of how the system *prints* them, is to inspect them.  We expect that `(list 'quote '(a b c))` should return a list whose `car` is the symbol `quote` and whose `cadr` is the list `(a b c)`.  This is what we get (in Dr. Racket 5.3 with language R<sup>5</sup>RS):

```
> (display (list 'quote '(a b c)))
'(a b c)
> (display (car (list 'quote '(a b c))))
quote
> (display (cadr (list 'quote '(a b c))))
(a b c)
```

We get similar results if we use `'qmmmt` instead of `'quote`:

```
> (display (list 'qmmmt '(a b c)))
(qmmmt (a b c))
> (display (car (list 'qmmmt '(a b c))))
qmmmt
> (display (cadr (list 'qmmmt '(a b c))))
(a b c)
```

The only difference is that in the first case, `display` displays the list whose `car` is the symbol `quote` using the shorthand that is available for such lists.  That is, instead of displaying `(quote (a b c))` it displayed `'(a b c)`.

Answer (score 4):

`'(a b c)` and `(quote (a b c))` are actually different notations for the same. So don't be surprised if your Lisp prints the shorter version.

In general `'<something>` is the same as `(quote <something>)`.

`QUOTE` is used in Lisp to mark expressions which should evaluate to themselves. Usually a list would be a function or macro call and a symbol would be a variable. If you want to treat those as data, you need to quote them.

Since `(quote <something>)` is used so often in Lisp, the abbreviated version `'<something>` has been introduced to save a bit of typing or reading...

Comment: I want to emphasize that in the question I'm using `'quote` not `quote`. And `'quote` is represented differently, not like `'qmmmt` for instance.

Comment: For example `(list 'quote '(a b c))` is represented as `'(a b c)`, `(list 'c 'quote '(a b c))` is represented as `(c quote (a b c))`, `(list 'quo '(a b c))` is represented as `(quo (a b c))`

Comment: @Graduate the system may _print_ the list `(quote abc)` and the list `(qmmmt abc)` differently (as `'abc` and `(qmmmt abc)`) respectively, but both are lists;  if you call `first` and `second` on them, you'll see the expected values.  This is just a matter of _printing_.

Comment: I was just interested why it prints differently.

Answer (score 2):

`display` emits some behaviors. Eg. `'(a . (b . (c . ())))` is displayed `(a b c)`. `'quote` is displayed `quote` and perhaps `'(quote x y)` is displayed `(quote x y)` while `'(quote x)` is displayed `'x` or `(quote x)`. Which one is implementation dependent but both mean the same.

As data (ie. quoted, like `(quote quote)` and it's abbrivation `'quote`) the result of the evaluation, the symbol `quote` is nothing special, for any LISP, just like `'+` and `'potato` happen to be the symbols `+` and `potato`. Any symbol that mean something when not quoted is no special when quoted.

Comment: It's very important to make it clear whether you're putting _values_ or _forms_ in your code blocks.  When you say that the `(quote quote)` is abbreviated `'quote`, you're talking about the value that is a list of length two and each of whose elements are the symbol `quote`.  When you say that `'+` and `'potato` are symbols, though, you mean that the _forms_ `'+` and `'potato`, when evaluated, produce the values that are the symbol `+` and the symbol `potato`.  Usually the meaning is clear from context, but this is a question _about_ what things mean in different contexts.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor With `(quote quote)` I was thinking as a form.. eg. quote being bound to a special form and that it's application turned the form into the (no special) symbol `quote`, just like '+ tuns into a no special symbol since it's quoted while evaluating `+` is quite different. It's not straight forward for an algol programmer as myself to find an analogy for this so it took some time getting used to :)