# behavior of quote in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, quote, repl-printed-representation

I'm used to `(quote x)` evaluating to `x`, `(quote (x y z))` evaluating to `(x y z)`, and `(car (quote (x y z))` evaluating to `x`.  The reasoning is simple: quote is a special form that does not evaluate its argument, but simply returns it as is.

I just started using Racket, and it thinks that `(quote x)` evaluates to `(quote x)`, `(quote (x y z))` evaluates to `(quote (x y z))`, and `(car (quote (x y z))` evaluates to `(quote x)`.

Well, actually, it prints these as `'x`, `'(x y z)`, and `'x`, respectively, but that's the same thing.

Can someone explain the reasoning here?  If, for some reason, `(quote (x y z))` evaluates to `(quote (x y z))`, shouldn't the car of that then be `quote`?  Where does `(quote x)` come from?

As far as I can tell, Racket, throughout the entire computation, internally behaves just as I'm used to, except that when it comes time to print the final result, it wraps it in a quote form.  Is this correct in all cases?  And if so, why would it want to do that?

Comment: See my note in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20643658/1281433): "As an additional complication, some systems (I'm thinking of some languages, Dr.  Racket, in particular) don't print the value of a form in the interactive prompt, but rather print a form that would produce the same (for certain interpretations of “the same”) values. For instance, you might evaluate '(1 . 2) and see the output (cons 1 2) because that's another form that would produce the same value."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of 'quote in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643147/meaning-of-quote-in-lisp)

Answer (score 3):

Racket evaluates the expressions in the same way as any Scheme. Racket however has in a special writer in the teaching languages. In DrRacket you can change the way values are printed. In the language menu, click the advanced button, and then take a look at the printing options.

Answer (score 0):

Racket (language) prints out the result of top level forms, not only when entered in the interaction window (REPL), but always. It's to ease developing I guess and in real world applications you don't have statements that doesn't amount to anything so a real application wouldn't have these lines displayed since you have `define` and an expression to start your program and you could return (void) from it to force no output..

If you were to change language to either `#!r6rs` or `#!r5rs` you quickly see that the only way to get the result of an evaluation in the definitions window would be if you explicitly used `display` on the result.

No matter the language used, `display` displays it correctly. For a REPL-print the language and setting control how it displays. Standard #!racket is to display in such way that putting it in a new expression wrapped with `display` would print exactly the same as if you would have wrapped the original expression with display.

```
(define test 'hello-world)
(display test) ;; displays hello-world and not 'hello-world
test           ;; displays 'hello-world in #!racket, nothing in R6RS unless in interactions window
```