# Converting a dotted pair to a two-element list in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to lisp and working on a homework problem to flatten a nested list.  I have my funciton working except it needs to 'remove' dotted pairs.  So given (1 (2 3) (4 . 5) ((6 7) (89))) my function should output (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).

So.. my actual question..

Given a dotted pair e.g `(1 . 2)`, how can I get the list `'(1 2)`?

Comment: You may want to experiment with the functions CONS and LIST. There are also a few other useful functions. You should have got some instructions with your lecture. What do you have tried so far?

Comment: Also, if you search for [\[lisp\] flatten](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blisp%5D+flatten), you'll find a number of related questions and answers here.  You may be able to find what you're looking for in those.

Comment: Apparently this was pretty straight forward using car and cdr.  I'm surprised by how little documentation there is on lisp relative to all of the other languages I've learned.

Comment: @rcj There's actually a whole lot out there; a hypertext version of the specification (the HyperSpec) is very good.  For this case, you should look at the [car and cdr accessors](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm) specifically, and chapter [14. Conses](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_.htm) more generally.

Comment: I guess when I say documentation I'm really talking about the ability to google questions I have.  Rather than just picking the one of the first couple google search results for basic questions, I have to sift through the bs and dig really deep into only half-relevant threads to get what I need.

Comment: @rcj When learning something as complex as a programming language, it will save you hours and hours of time if you make it a point early on to find an authoritative reference (in this case, the HyperSpec), and to skim through the table of contents, and perhaps some sections that look interesting.  Obviously you don't need to memorize the whole thing from the beginning, but you'll have an idea of what's out there, and where to find it.  A question like this one, to be honest, is about some pretty basic functions in Common Lisp;  you're not likely to find many Q&A threads about them, precisely…

Comment: …because they're fairly basic.  Even for complex issues, Q&A hunting isn't going to be a great way to learn the standard functionality.  That's what the documentation is for.  For Lisp, you might also be interested in [lispdoc.com](http://lispdoc.com/), "a search engine for documentation of the Common Lisp programming language and many of its libraries."  It searches the HyperSpec, some other useful books, and libraries.

Comment: There's also some meta-searching that you should be doing too:  while this isn't a perfect heuristic, if you're searching for solutions to some task, and it doesn't seem like anyone's ever done it before, then you might want to ask whether it's the most suitable approach.  In this case (as the results for `[lisp] flatten` show) there are lots of solutions to flattening lists that don't require turning `'(1 . 2)` into `(1 2)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cons cell is a structure that has two parts, called its `car` and its `cdr`.  The pair `(1 . 2)` is a cons cell whose `car` is `1` and whose `cdr` is `2`.  Lists in Lisps are built up from cons cells and `nil`.  How this works is described in lots of places, including the answer to [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433)  A list is either the empty list `()` (also called `nil`), or a cons whose `car` is the first element of the list and whose `cdr` is another list which is the rest of the list.  That means that a list

```
(1 2)
```

is built of cons cells and `nil` as

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))
```

If you've already got `(1 . 2)`, then you can get `1` and `2` with `car` and `cdr`. You'd put them back together as just described.  That is,

```
(let ((x '(1 . 2)))
  (cons (car x) (cons (cdr x) nil)))
```

Alternatively, you could just use `list`:

```
(let ((x '(1 . 2)))
  (list (car x) (cdr x)))
```

If you want to reuse the same cons cell, you could *replace* the `cdr` of the cell with `(cons 2 nil)`.  For instance (and note that we're not quoting the pair anymore, because modifying literal data is undefined behavior):

```
(let ((x (cons 1 2)))
  (setf (cdr x) (cons (cdr x) nil))
  x)
```

That could also be

```
(let ((x (cons 1 2)))
  (setf (cdr x) (list (cdr x)))
  x)
```

You could also use [`rplacd`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rplaca.htm%27):

```
(let ((x (cons 1 2)))
  (rplacd x (list (cdr x)))
  x)
```